# Core Data crashes while attempting to read external data

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app that stores images in Core Data using External Storage. From time to time I get crash reports with the following error (in this particular instance it's running on a M1 Mac via Catalyst):

```
Unable to open file with path /Users/user/Library/Group Containers/group.myapp/.myapp_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/61681DBF-B1A4-4325-9104-E21A1218F046 (92)
```

The relevant stack trace bit looks like this:

```
0  CoreFoundation +0xfc408  __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib +0x1aea4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData +0x12cda0       +[_PFRoutines readExternalReferenceDataFromFile:]
3  CoreData +0xe9db8        -[_PFExternalReferenceData _attemptToMapData:]
4  CoreData +0xd7894        -[_PFExternalReferenceData _retrieveExternalData]
5  Foundation +0x46f2f8     specialized static Data._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(_:)
6  MyApp +0x15eb80          Image.thumbnailImage.getter (Image.swift:25:22)
```

All I'm doing in Image.swift:25:22 is declaring a variable with the contents of the image:

```
let data = self.thumbnail // 'thumbnail' is my Binary Data attribute
```

I've tried to reproduce this crash on my machine by intentionally deleting, corrupting and changing permissions on external storage files but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have the slightest idea of what's going on, or how to prevent or fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that Thumbnail is too big for reading into memory? Sometimes memory can be limited

Comment: The stack trace makes it clear that the error is directly from attempting to read the file. If it's not a size problem like @ArikSegal suggested, I'd go look at the code that saves the image to see what could go wrong there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's not, it's the name of the binary data attribute

Comment: @TomHarrington but that is taken care of by Core Data under the hood, isn't it? All I do when I save the image is set my `thumbnail` Core Data attribute to the image data.

Comment: @Wes It should be, but this is an unusual failure, and I'd consider the entire life-cycle of the data to see where something could be going wrong.